# Cassava parsing error in haskell

Tags: csv, parsing, haskell

Im trying to convert a csv into a vector using cassava. The csv Im trying to convert is the fischer iris data set, used for machine learning. It consists of four doubles and one string.
My code is the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where
import Data.Csv
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
import qualified Data.Vector as V

data Iris = Iris
  { sepal_length  :: !Double
  , sepal_width   :: !Double
  , petal_length  :: !Double
  , petal_width   :: !Double
  , iris_type     :: !String
 } deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

instance FromNamedRecord Iris where
  parseNamedRecord r =
    Iris
      <$> r .: "sepal_length"
      <*> r .: "sepal_width"
      <*> r .: "petal_length"
      <*> r .: "petal_width"
      <*> r .: "iris_type"

printIris :: Iris -> IO ()
printIris r  = putStrLn $  show (sepal_length r) ++ show (sepal_width r)
   ++ show(petal_length r) ++ show(petal_length r) ++ "hola"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  csvData <- BS.readFile "./iris/test-iris"
  print csvData
  case decodeByName csvData of
    Left err -> putStrLn err
    -- forM : O(n) Apply the monadic action to all elements of the vector,
    -- yielding a vector of results.
    Right (h, v) -> V.forM_ v $ printIris
```

When I run this, it seems as if the csvData is correctly formatted, the first lines from the print csvData return the following:

```
"5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa\n4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris- setosa\n4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa\n4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa\n5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa\n5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa\n4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa\n5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa\n4.4,2.9,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa\n4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa\n5.4,3.7,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa\n4.8,3.4,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa\n4.8,3.0,1.4,0.1,Iris-setosa\n4.3,3.0,1.1,0.1,Iris-setosa\n5.8,4.0,1.2,0.2,Iris-setosa\n5.7,4.4,1.5,0.4,Iris-set
```

But I get the following error:

```
parse error (Failed reading: conversion error: no field named "sepal_length")  at 
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4 (truncated)
```

Does anybody have any idea as to why I can be getting this error? The csv has no missing values, and if I replace the line which produces the error for another row I get the same error.

Comment: Hello nat, and welcome to the site!  We generally try to keep questions extremely to-the-point so I've gone ahead and trimmed yours a bit, feel free to edit it again if you aren't happy with my changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears your data does not have a header, which is assumed by [`decodeByName`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Csv.html#v:decodeByName)

> The data is assumed to be preceeded by a header.

Add a header, or use `decode NoHeader` and the `FromRecord` type class.

Comment: I added a header and still have the same error: sepal_length, sepal_width, petal_length, petal_width, type
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa ...

Comment: there are spaces in your header that somehow cassava is preserving. I could get it to parse this header with no spaces `sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,iris_type`

Comment: using the same code? I fixed the header and I still get the same error, maybe its something with my configuration file?

Comment: It worked!!! I had one of the names in the header wrong! thank you :) :)